# Splunk HEC: Start sending events in JSON format with pre existing raw events

Tags: json, splunk, raw-data

We are using Splunk Enterprise v 6.6.3. All our indexed events are raw events (logs) and we are planning to use Splunk HEC and send the events in JSON format.

My question: does sending the new events in JSON format affect everything that we have today in Splunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once events are indexed in Splunk they cannot change.  Nothing you do with new events will affect anything already in Splunk.